# JavaScript regex to accept values between 00.01 to 999.99999

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have the following regex

```
var pattern = /^(\d{2,3})?(?:\.\d{2,5})?$/;

//The value must be always lesser than 999.99999
if(!pattern.test(billRate.value)|| parseFloat(billRate.value) > parseFloat("999.99999"))
{
    alert("Invalid It accepts values between 00.01 to 999.99999");
    return false;
}
```

The minimum value should be always 00.01 and the max value is 999.99999.

Also the regex should always check that there is minimum of two numbers before decimal point and minimum of two decimals after.

Unfortunately the above regex is not working properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the people who have down voted and you could see that i have posted as what i have tried. i am sure that this question will certainly help few while may not for all the super coders.

Comment: Well as per your regex 123.123456789 will fail do you want it to fail ?

Comment: @Code Maniac  Thank you for your reply. Yes it should fail

Comment: Well than if you just check for 00.00 by using if condition your regex seems to work fine.

Comment: See [`^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)\d{2,3}\.\d{2,5}$`](https://regex101.com/r/7MxzLr/1).

Comment: Wikitor, `00.00001` is less than `00.01`

Comment: **Why are you trying to check numerical value with a regex**??? The "minimum of two numbers before and after a decimal point" is a suitable (and simple) problem to be solved by regex: `/^\d{2,}\.\d{2,}$`. But checking the actual value should just be left to the float comparison, not a crazy complex regex... Unless you have a *very good, unusual reason* to strictly need a pure regex solution for this.

Comment: @TomLord - I use a free software tool to generate a regex for any range of numbers float or not, because it's easy.

Comment: The fact that such a regex CAN be used does not make it a good solution. This is a classic example of an XY problem. As I said above, I'd highly recommend only using a regex to validate the basic format, but validate the actual value via float comparison.

Comment: @TomLord - Yeah, I've seen that said before on SO. Consider that you say it's ok to use regex to validate the basic format `^\d{2,}\.\d{2,}$` but not to use regex to validate the value. If a %100 accurate regex is generated automatically for every range, you wouldn't have to validate via string to number conversion and a Boolean. The _first rule_ is, you can't validate floating point numbers with Booleans. One is internally binary, the other is externally decimal. When you validate as decimal text it stays decimal.

Comment: @sln Thanks and will use this ^\d{2,}\.\d{2,}$ and validate via the programming for others

Comment: @sln *"The first rule is, you can't validate floating point numbers with Booleans."* --- Yes you can. You already did that, above. Floating point numbers have their limitations, but that doesn't make them completely useless for comparisons.

Comment: Your argument seems to be "if I can already generate a regex that works, then why isn't that good enough?" ... Well for a start, your regex generation was flawed, since you wanted to validate the format of the string as well as its numerical representation. And secondly, what happens whens someone (perhaps your future self) wants to read+understand+edit this code? A garbled mess of regex isn't particularly helpful. And lastly, a pure regex solution could easily become far less performant than a basic float comparison implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

`^(?:0?00\.(?:01\d{0,3}|0[2-9]\d{0,3}|[1-9]\d{1,4})|(?:0?0[1-9]|0?[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2})\.\d{2,5})$`

Unfortunately, I don't have a way to test it.

Readable version

```
 ^   

 (?:
      0? 00 \.                      #  000.01000 - 000.99999
      (?:
           01 \d{0,3} 
        |  0 [2-9] \d{0,3} 
        |  [1-9] \d{1,4} 
      )
   |  
      (?:                           #  001.00000 - 999.99999
           0? 0 [1-9] 
        |  0? [1-9] \d 
        |  [1-9] \d{2} 
      )
      \.
      \d{2,5} 
 )

 $
```

Comment: this really serves my purpose and i have used https://www.regextester.com/ to test your regex